# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function on __soapCall to PostNL

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to make a __soapCall using a WDSL client. But i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function 
("GenerateBarcode") is not a valid method for this service in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/postnl/postnl.php:75
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/postnl/postnl.php(75): SoapClient-
>__soapCall('GenerateBarcode', Array)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/postnl/postnl.php(110): Postnl-
>GenerateBarcode('DEVC', 11223344)
#2 {main}
```

I'm trying to make the call to this API:

https://developer.postnl.nl/apis/barcode-webservice/documentation

Instantiate client:

```
private $client;

public function __construct(){
    // CreateSoapClient and assign to class
    $this->createClient('https://testservice.postnl.com/CIF_SB/BarcodeWebService/1_1/?wsdl');
    //Create Soap security
    $this->createSoapSecurity($this->username, $this->password);
    //Setting headers to client
    $this->setSoapHeaders($securityHeader);
}

private function createClient($url){
    //Create Client
    $this->client = new SoapClient($url,['trace' => true]);
}

private function createSoapSecurity($username,$password){
    //Create security
    $username = new SoapVar($username, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Username', self::XMLNS);
    $password = new SoapVar(sha1($password), XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Password', self::XMLNS);

    $usernameToken = new SoapVar([$username, $password], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'UsernameToken', self::XMLNS);
    $security = new SoapVar([$usernameToken], SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'Security', self::XMLNS);

    $this->securityHeader = $security;
}

private function setSoapHeaders($securityHeader) {
    // Set soap headers to client
    $this->client->__setSoapHeaders($SecurityHeader);
}
```

When i vardump `$this->client->__getFunctions()`:
it returns correctly:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(80) "GenerateBarcodeResponse GenerateBarcode(GenerateBarcodeMessage $GenerateBarcode)" }
```

The call:

```
public function GenerateBarcode($customerCode, $customerNumber){
    $this->createMessage(); 

    $this->createBarcode('3S');


    return $this->client->__soapcall('GenerateBarcode', [
        'MessageID' => $this->MessageID,
        'MessageTimeStamp' => $this->MessageTimeStamp,
        'CustomerCode' => $this->customerCode,
        'CustomerNumber' => $this->customerNumber,
        'Type' => $this->type,
        'Serie' => $this->serie
    ]);

}
```

It returns the error..

Checked the soap headers on Pratheek Katal request. This was the example header i needed to create.

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>password (sha1 hash)</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

The php code i use to try to make that:

```
$ns = $this->XMLNS;
    $headerbody = [
        'wsse:UsernameToken' => [
            'wsse:Username' => $this->username,
            'wsse:Password' => sha1($this->password),
        ],
    ];
    $header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'wsse:Security', $headerbody);
    // Set soap headers to client
    $this->client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Still getting the same error...

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Are you setting the SOAP Headers right? I can see you are using [SOAPVar](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapvar.php) but did you have a look at [SOAPHeader](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php)

Comment: @prateekkathal updated the answer, checked soapheaders still getting the same error